# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined react-native expo sdk 40.0.0

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am getting this error constantly when I update the react-native expo app from SDK 36.0.0 to 40.0.0. I have searched many things on the internet but not found any solution which can help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKz8p.jpg)
I am pasting my package.json file here

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@highcharts/highcharts-react-native": "^3.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "expo-activity-feed": "^0.9.1",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.3",
    "expo-contacts": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-mixpanel-analytics": "0.0.7",
    "expo-permissions": "~10.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.6.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.6.1",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-gmailtype-textinput": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "^1.1.14",
    "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^13.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.0.0",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.0",
    "victory-native": "^32.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined  react-native expo SDK 40.0.0
> I am getting the same error in expo 40 as well

Comment: When do you see this error? When you run `npm install`? When you perform an operation in your app?

Comment: When I run expo start

Comment: Due to breaking changes, Expo recommends upgrading incrementally one version at a time: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/